# Identity column error

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have made a stored procedure for inserting values in table through front end. I have a IDENTITY column as ID in the stored procedure. But whenever I am adding it, it is giving as Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BusinessUnit' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. Please see the code for your reference.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_BusinessUnit]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Id int,
@Name nvarchar(100)
AS

BEGIN

     INSERT INTO Career.BusinessUnit(Id,Name) values (@Id,@Name)
END
```

Also see the button click as it is added from front end.

```
protected void btnAddBusiness_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Add_BusinessUnit";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBusinessUnitOther.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // BindContrydropdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);//You Can Haave Messagebox here
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  An `identity` column is supposed to be set automatically.  You have to set identify insert to off on the table if you want to set it manually -- but you should do so with great caution.

Comment: you don't need to set value for identity column . it will set automatically .

Comment: @AmitKumar: so should I remove it both from SP and Code behind for ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting manualy the value of identity column .
your SP should be like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_BusinessUnit]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Name nvarchar(100)
AS

BEGIN

     INSERT INTO Career.BusinessUnit(Name) values (@Name)
END
```

and your c# code should be

```
protected void btnAddBusiness_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Add_BusinessUnit";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBusinessUnitOther.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            BindContrydropdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);//You Can Haave Messagebox here
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not getting inserted at that time when I check the dropdown list, it is getting when I refresh the page. However when I check the table the value is inserted. what to do for that ?

Comment: @Saba: as i can see , you have written this code on click event of button, not on check event.

Comment: Yes, i have to add that textbox value on button click. But i am not able to see that in the list

Comment: After inserting this code , you need to call that function , that is binding your List.
in this code `BindContrydropdown();` is commented, uncomment it .

Comment: That is for the Country, not for business unit. Will that work ? r u sure ?

Comment: I think i have to make a same fucntion as BindContrydropdown() for business unit also.

Comment: @Saba: yes . and you need to call that function after inserting that value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59938/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-saba).

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Server Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_BusinessUnit]
@Id int  OUTPUT,
@Name nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
     INSERT INTO Career.BusinessUnit(Name) 
     values (@Name)

     SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END

// Call procedure


DECLARE @ID INT;

EXECUTE [dbo].[Add_BusinessUnit] 'Mark', @ID OUTPUT

SELECT @ID; --<-- Variable will be populated with newly inserted ID value
```

### C# Code

```
// define connection and command, in using blocks to ensure disposal
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(pvConnectionString ))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Add_BusinessUnit", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // set up the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    // set parameter values
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;

    // open connection and execute stored procedure
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // read output value from @Id
    int NewID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value);
    conn.Close();
}
```